# NP-hardness of modified distance-colouring of graphs

Tags: graphs, np-complete, trees, np-hard, colorings

Given a graph $G =(V,E)$, a set of colors $\mathcal{C}=\{0,1,2,3,...,c-1\}$, and an integer $r$, I want to know if I can find a coloring procedure that can assign a color to each nodes (all nodes must be colored) in such a way that each node can find all distinctive colors around it within a radius of $r$, i.e., for every vertex $v \in V$, $N^r[v]$ has all colors of $\mathcal{C}$.

How should I prove that this problem is a NP-complete problem(it is fairly easy to show the certificate part and NP part, but I have difficulty reducing this problem to well know NP-complete problems.)

Note that this problem is different from the $k$-coloring problem.
Note that it is not a problem to have same colors on neighbors.
I solved the NP part but I do not know how to reduce this problem.

Comment: This is NPC for r equals one - that's a well known problem. I can give you a reference later on if you want.

Comment: is it possible to give me a reference for that @Juho?

Comment: There you go - hope it's useful. May I ask if there's any particular motivation or application for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer to your problem, but I have an answer for a different problem.

Let the *Annotated Colorful Neighborhood*-problem be as follows.

**Annotated 2-Colorful 1-Neighborhood**
**Input**: $G = (V, E), k, S \subseteq V$
**Output**: Is there a coloring of vertices of $V \setminus S$ such that every vertex $v \in S$ has at least one red neighbor and one blue neighbor.

This problem is NP-hard when $G$ is a bipartite graph and $S$ is one of the sides, and even if every vertex in $S$ has degree 3.

The reduction is from *NAE-3-SAT without positive literals*.  In NAE-3-SAT without positive literals, the input is a set of $n$ variables $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ and a set of relations
$$R(x^1_1, x^1_2, x^1_3), R(x^2_1, x^2_2, x^2_3), ... R(x^m_1, x^m_2, x^m_3)$$
and the question is if it is possible to assign truth values to $x_i$ such that not all $x^j_1, x^j_2, x^j_3$ have the same truth value for any $1 \leq j \leq m$.

The problem can be seen as a special case of *Set Splitting*.  In the Set Splitting problem, we are given a set $\mathcal U$ and a set of subsets $\mathcal F \subseteq 2^{\mathcal U}$, and the question is whether there exists a partitioning of $\mathcal U$ into $S_1$ and $S_2$ such that for every set $F \in \mathcal F$, $F \cap S_1 \neq \emptyset$ and $F \cap S_2 \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: sorry but this answer does not solve my problem

Comment: My problem is the modified distance-colouring of graphs

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe (for $r=1$) falls under the $[\sigma,\rho]$-partitioning framework with several hardness results available (see e.g., [1]). In such a problem, we want to color the vertices of a graph in $k$ colors such that for each vertex, the number of neighbors it has with its own color in in $p$ and the number of neighbors it has with each different color than its own is in $\rho$. So note that $\sigma$ and $\rho$ are sets here.

For example, if you mean that you want a coloring where each vertex $v$ sees each of the $k$ colors in its neighborhood (again, I'm speaking only about $r=1$), we have $\sigma = \mathbb{P} = \{1, 2, \ldots \}$ and similarly $\rho = \mathbb{P}$. If you think about what the color classes are in this case, you are actually partitioning the vertex set into [total dominating sets](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotalDominatingSet.html). By Theorem 3 in [1], this problem is NP-complete for 2 colors. If you just search online for "partitioning into total dominating sets", you will find more hardness results. In short, the problem is NP-complete for $k \geq 2$, and remains hard for many restricted graph classes as well.

I don't know if anyone has studied the problem explicitly for $r > 1$ as you describe.

---

[1] [Heggernes, Pinar, and Jan Arne Telle. "Partitioning graphs into generalized dominating sets." Nord. J. Comput. 5.2 (1998): 128-142.](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Pinar-Heggernes/publication/2483943_Partitioning_Graphs_Into_Generalized_Dominating_Sets/links/54b5149c0cf26833efd063a2/Partitioning-Graphs-Into-Generalized-Dominating-Sets.pdf)